# Webdriver inheritance between clases

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Question is probably really trivial but I cannot handle it in proper way. I'm using Selenium with NUnit, having two clases:

1) "DemoTest" which involves one simply test "DummyTest":

```
    public class DemoTest : TestBase
    {
        public class RunTest
        {
            [Test, Category("Main-Tests"), Order(1)]
            public void DummyTest()
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

2) "Test base" class where I want to place all of the NUnit/ driver attributes like: "SetUp" / "TearDown"

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestBase
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get { return driver; }
        set { driver = value; }
    }
    public string pageURL = "http://automationpractice.com/";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(pageURL);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Close();
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

As NUnit attributes are declared (SetUp section) my test from DemoTest class should at least move on the page under pageURL variable.

Result is that after running a test it's immediately jump on "passed" without opening the specified address.

"DemoTest" inherits from "Test base" class. Nuget packages are installed correctly. When I'm placing test inside the "Test base" class everything works correctly but I want to have it separated.

Comment: You haven't said how you are running your tests (which runner) or what exactly happens to show you whether the navigation takes place. Since the test itself is empty, there will of course be no results to examine.

Comment: @Charlie Nunit runner, right after the test runs there is passing lamp with execution time 4 ms. Test is empty but it should use the [SetUp] configuration and use "navigate" functionality. Or maybe I'm missing a reference between classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix **DemoTest** class as follows:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class DemoTest : TestBase
{
    [Test, Category("Main-Tests"), Order(1)]
    public void DummyTest()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Can you explain me why it's a problem when class is "inside a class"?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it seems to me that the problem is not that you are using a nested class, but that you forgot to set the `[TestFixture]` attribute